# Make the Google Maps Javascript API sit in a container in React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API in React but I'm having issues with sizing and positioning it. It's fine if I want it to take up an entire page but if I want it to sit among other items on a page, it doesn't behave as I would expect.

I've put it within a container with the width and height set to 500px but it just spills out like this -
[example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Wej.png)

I've tried following this - [React google-maps-react, Change property of hidden div from google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47106627/react-google-maps-react-change-property-of-hidden-div-from-google-maps-api?rq=1)

It works at first but the minute I refresh or add anything else to the page, it breaks. It just seems very fragile.

Here's my js code -

```
import React from "react";
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker } from 'google-maps-react';
import "./stylesheet.css";

class MapContainer extends React.Component {
    render(){
        const mapStyles = {
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
        };

        return (
            <div id="mapContainer">
                <Map 
                google={this.props.google}
                zoom={13}
                style={mapStyles}
                initialCenter={{ lat: 51.240738, lng: -0.573903}}    
                >
                </Map>
            </div>
        )
    }   
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: '[my google maps api key]'
  })(MapContainer);
```

And here's the css -

```
#mapContainer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `containerStyle` props. It will take CSS style object - optional, commonly when you want to change from the default of position "absolute". This is mentioned in the google-maps-react library [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#additional-map-props).

Here is a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/containerstyle-xntepd?file=src/App.js) and code snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker } from "google-maps-react";
import "./style.css";

class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const containerStyle = {
      position: "relative",
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%"
    };

    return (
      <div id="mapContainer">
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={13}
          containerStyle={containerStyle}
          initialCenter={{ lat: 51.240738, lng: -0.573903 }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: '[my google maps api key]'
})(MapContainer);
```